# Is it possible to restore an Oracle DB on a different Operating System?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to restore a backup of an Oracle 10.2.0.2.0 database which runs on UNIX to an Oracle 10g Express Edition (10.2.0.1.0) instance on Windows?

Comment: What sort of backup do you have?  RMAN?  Export?  Copies of datafiles?

Comment: What are you trying to do, restore a backup for test or just move some data for testing purposes?

Comment: @oluies - restore a backup to compare some data

Comment: @APC - The files are all .dbf files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DBF files cannot simply be copied over.

A proper database backup includes the SYSTEM (and SYSAUX) tablespaces which will have some features that the express edition won't support (a whole bunch of stuff requiring java for a start) so I'd be very surprised if it is successful.

An EXPDP / IMPDP should work (providing you are not using features incompatible with Express Edition). Also look at transportable tablespaces which may or may not work depending on your unix platform.

Answer (score 0):

With impdp/expdp you can do it

Comment: Go on then, any details about *how* to do it with these tools?